# Compiling Jasper Reports when Deployed to Tomcat 8

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, jasper-reports

Having issues using the JasperCompileManager.compileReport(myReport); when having a Simple Spring MVC Application deployed in Tomcat8.

Including the following dependencies :

```
....Spring Dependencies 4.1.6 Release...

<dependency>
    <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasper-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.15</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.1</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

I have a controller endpoint calling the following code in a Service class. (The code passes Unit & Integration Tests outside of the web app.)

```
 public JasperReport getJasperReport(String filePath)
{
    try {
        //        File f = new File(filePath);
        File tmpFile = new File("C:\\myReport.jrxml");
        return fromFile(tmpFile);
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        log.error(MyAppService.class.getName(),ex);
    }
    return null;
}


private JasperReport fromFile(File f) throws JRException {
    JasperDesign jd;
    JasperReport jr = null;
    jd = JRXmlLoader.load(f);
    jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
    return jr;
}
```

Getting the following Exception when calling the endpoint.

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.consumeBinaryExpression(Parser.java:1325)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.consumeRule(Parser.java:5961)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:8491)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:8656)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:8621)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.dietParse(Parser.java:7420)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.beginToCompile(Compiler.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:315)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJdtCompiler.compileUnits(JRJdtCompiler.java:167)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:201)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:354)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:614)
    at com.mvcapp.web.controller.MvcAppAccessController.fromFile(MvcAppAccessController.java:190)
    at com.mvcapp.web.controller.MvcAppAccessController.convertFileToByteArray(MvcAppAccessController.java:168)
    at com.mvcapp.web.controller.MvcAppAccessController.uploadFileHandler(MvcAppAccessController.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2407)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2396)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
20-Aug-2015 12:12:02.850 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-12] com.mvcapp.web.controller.MvcAppAccessController.convertFileToByteArray null
 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error compiling report design.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:242)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:354)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:614)
    at com.mvcapp.web.controller.MvcAppAccessController.fromFile(MvcAppAccessController.java:190)
    at com.mvcapp.web.controller.MvcAppAccessController.convertFileToByteArray(MvcAppAccessController.java:168)
    at com.mvcapp.web.controller.MvcAppAccessController.uploadFileHandler(MvcAppAccessController.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2407)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2396)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.consumeBinaryExpression(Parser.java:1325)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.consumeRule(Parser.java:5961)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:8491)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:8656)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:8621)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.dietParse(Parser.java:7420)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.beginToCompile(Compiler.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:315)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJdtCompiler.compileUnits(JRJdtCompiler.java:167)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:201)
    ... 44 more
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have aspectjtools.jar in your classpath, can you try compiling it by removing it from the classpath?